# redirect to login when session is getting timeout after a ajax call

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have problem with ajax call text, when the session is getting timeout.
i need to know How to redirect to Login page when Session is expired in asp core application after a ajax call?

Comment: my ajax methode :  $formContainer.load('DossierTache/CreatePopUp', function () {...}),after call it session is getting timeout, i need to redirect user to login page or to show notification for session timeout

Answer (score 0):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class AuthenticateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private const string RequestedWithHeader = "X-Requested-With";
        private const string XmlHttpRequest = "XMLHttpRequest";

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionData") == null)
            {
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[RequestedWithHeader] == XmlHttpRequest)
                {
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                }
                else
                {
                    bool NoFilter = true;

                    foreach (var filterDescriptors in filterContext.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors)
                    {
                        if (filterDescriptors.Filter.GetType() == typeof(IAllowAnonymous))
                        {
                            NoFilter = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    if (NoFilter)
                    {
                        var url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
                        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToPageResult("/Account/Login", new { area = "Identity", returnUrl = url });
                    }

                }
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but i still have the some problem , this method (OnActionExecuting()) isn't excuted if the session is getting timeout. the ajax call render "the server responded with a statut of 401"  without redirect to login page